swapExactTokensForTokens error TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED even after approval?
I've read almost every question on here referencing uniswapv2 swapExactTokensForTokens and I'm still getting the same error (below).  Here are the specifics:
Environment: local node
Infrastructure: ethers.js(v. 6.11.1) and hardhat (v. 2.22.8)
Chain: Ethereum mainnet
What should the smart contract do?: accept an array of trades to be executed and run swapExactTokensForTokens on a loop until all trades are completed. By design, the first inputToken is always WETH, and the final outputToken is always WETH.  I have 10,000 WETH in the test wallet at the time of attempting to execute these trades (which are always far below 10,000 WETH)
What's going wrong?: The error pasted below occurs each time swapExactTokensForTokens is called.  I am certain this is where the break is occurring, as I have gone line by line and determined that each action is occurring prior to this one.  I have tested using a simple printed string with event Test as you will see below.  I have also ensured that the amountIn is being passed as an integer, the amountOutMin is 0, and the path is correctly two addresses in an array format.  However, the odd thing is that, while swapExactTokensForTokens is active, nothing inside the loop will work.  But when I turn off swapExactTokensForTokens, everything up to that function will run properly. I also made sure to approve on the smart contract AND the javascript calling it.  What could be going wrong here?
Here's the error
Swap Failed: Error: could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32603, "data": { "data": "0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000245472616e7366657248656c7065723a205452414e534645525f46524f4d5f4641494c454400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "message": "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'", "txHash": "0xef80c53af6eb3c69aba5832f3541861e76962613eca6e80dabf12e0f9a85155d" }, "message": "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'" }, payload={ "id": 267718, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_sendRawTransaction", "params": [ "0x02f873827a698203df843b9aca00843b9aca10830a14f094e8c3f27d20472e4f3c546a3f73c04b54dd72871d8084ffe7dc4ec080a0e2ac8538700c2d4acd587e92949ddb32a90351ab6e268a8e1b2b4c3fab9a2b86a055347dde6ff9b30e0264de64095644df9a5d909facd53dfc0718c949662f4064" ] }, code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.11.1)
    at makeError (/Users/TrentKennelly/dfsBot/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:129:21)
    at JsonRpcProvider.getRpcError (/Users/TrentKennelly/dfsBot/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:722:41)
    at /Users/TrentKennelly/dfsBot/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:302:45
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
  error: {
    code: -32603,
    message: "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'",
    data: {
      message: "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'",
      txHash: '0xef80c53af6eb3c69aba5832f3541861e76962613eca6e80dabf12e0f9a85155d',
      data: '0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000245472616e7366657248656c7065723a205452414e534645525f46524f4d5f4641494c454400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    }
  },
  payload: {
    method: 'eth_sendRawTransaction',
    params: [
      '0x02f873827a698203df843b9aca00843b9aca10830a14f094e8c3f27d20472e4f3c546a3f73c04b54dd72871d8084ffe7dc4ec080a0e2ac8538700c2d4acd587e92949ddb32a90351ab6e268a8e1b2b4c3fab9a2b86a055347dde6ff9b30e0264de64095644df9a5d909facd53dfc0718c949662f4064'
    ],
    id: 267718,
    jsonrpc: '2.0'
  },
  shortMessage: 'could not coalesce error'
} 

A note on this error.  If I enter the first 10 characters into this decoder then I get back a simple Error(string) response.  Not very helpful.
Here's the smart contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

//Libraries and interfaces go here

contract ArbitrageFlashLoan {
    address payable public account;

    struct TradeInstruction {
        address arbPair;
        bool router;
        address routerTarget;
        address inputToken;
        address outputToken;
        uint256 amountIn;
        uint256 amountOut;
    }

    TradeInstruction[] public tradeInstructions;

    event TradeInstructionAdded(
        address indexed arbPair,
        bool router,
        address routerTarget,
        address inputToken,
        address outputToken,
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOut
    );
    
    event Test(string message);

    // Function to add trade instructions
    function addTradeInstruction(
        address _arbPair,
        bool _router,
        address _routerTarget,
        address _inputToken,
        address _outputToken,
        uint256 _amountIn,
        uint256 _amountOut
    ) external {
        TradeInstruction memory newInstruction = TradeInstruction({
            arbPair: _arbPair,
            router: _router,
            routerTarget: _routerTarget,
            inputToken: _inputToken,
            outputToken: _outputToken,
            amountIn: _amountIn,
            amountOut: _amountOut
        });
        tradeInstructions.push(newInstruction);
        emit Test("Line 1991")
    }

    // Function to execute stored trade instructions
    function executeSwaps() public { 

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tradeInstructions.length; i++) {
            TradeInstruction memory instruction = tradeInstructions[i];
            address[] memory path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = instruction.inputToken;
            path[1] = instruction.outputToken;
            IUniswapV2Router02 swapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(instruction.routerTarget);
            emit Test("Line 2012");

            IERC20(instruction.inputToken).approve(instruction.routerTarget, instruction.amountIn); 
            emit Test("Line 2014");

            swapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens( 
                instruction.amountIn,
                0,
                path,
                address(this),
                block.timestamp + 120
            );

            emit Test("Line 2024");

        }

        uint256 outputTokenBalance = IERC20(tradeInstructions[tradeInstructions.length - 1].outputToken).balanceOf(address(this));
        emit Test("Line 2035");
        // Transfer the output tokens to the account
        IERC20(tradeInstructions[tradeInstructions.length - 1].outputToken).transfer(account, outputTokenBalance);

        // Clear the trade instructions after execution
        delete tradeInstructions;
        emit Test("Line 2041");
        
    }
}

Here's the javascript that calls it:
//In this function I monitor live swaps and use other functions (not really germane to the question) to build the array

const main = async () => {

    pairs = originalPairs.filter(p => p.arbPair != reservesExcluded.arbPair)

    pairs.map(async (pair, _) => {

        const pairContract = new ethers.Contract( pair.arbPair, IUniswapV2Pair.abi, provider);

        pairArray.push(pairContract)

        console.log(`arbPair: ${pair.arbPair}, tokens: ${pair.token0} / ${pair.token1}`)

        let profitablePath;
        
        const swapEventFragment = pairContract.filters.Swap();

        pairContract.on(swapEventFragment, async() => {
                
                if (!isExecuting) {

                    isExecuting = true
                    try {
                        const currentPair = pairArray.find((p) => p === pairContract);

                        const pathways = await dfs(currentPair, pair, reservesExcluded);
                            
                        if (!pathways || pathways.length === 0) {

                            console.log("\nNo Pathway Found")
                            console.log("-------------------------------\n")
                            isExecuting = false

                        } 

                        const profitability = await determineProfitability(pathways);

                        if (!profitability ) {

                            console.log("\nNo Profitable Path Found")
                            console.log("-------------------------------\n")

                        } else {

                            console.log(`Profitability V2: ${profitability}`)
                        
                            profitablePath = profitability.path;

                            const tradeInstructions = profitablePath.map((tradeStep, index) => {

                                let inputToken, outputToken, amountIn, amountOut

                                    amountIn = tradeStep.amountIn;

                                amountOut = tradeStep.amountOut;

                                if ( index === 0 && tradeStep.reservesToken0 === 'WETH' ) {

                                    inputToken = tradeStep.reservesToken0Addr
                                    outputToken = tradeStep.reservesToken1Addr

                                } else if ( index === 0 && tradeStep.reservesToken1 === 'WETH' ) {

                                    inputToken = tradeStep.reservesToken1Addr
                                    outputToken = tradeStep.reservesToken0Addr

                                } else if ( index > 0 ) {

                                    if ( tradeStep.reservesToken0Addr === profitablePath[index - 1].reservesToken0Addr || 
                                        tradeStep.reservesToken0Addr === profitablePath[index - 1].reservesToken1Addr ) {

                                        inputToken = tradeStep.reservesToken0Addr

                                    } else if ( tradeStep.reservesToken1Addr === profitablePath[index - 1].reservesToken0Addr || 
                                                tradeStep.reservesToken1Addr === profitablePath[index - 1].reservesToken1Addr ) {
                                                    
                                        inputToken = tradeStep.reservesToken1Addr                            

                                    } else {

                                        console.log("There's a hole in the inputToken logic")

                                    }

                                    if ( inputToken === tradeStep.reservesToken0Addr ) {

                                        outputToken = tradeStep.reservesToken1Addr
                                        
                                    } else {

                                        outputToken = tradeStep.reservesToken0Addr

                                    }

                                } else {

                                    console.log("There's a hole in the tradeInstructions logic")
                                    
                                }
                                
                                return {

                                    arbPair: tradeStep.arbPair,
                                    router: tradeStep.router === uRouter ? uRouter : sRouter,
                                    routerTarget: tradeStep.router === uRouter ? uRouter.target : sRouter.target,
                                    inputToken: inputToken,
                                    outputToken: outputToken,
                                    amountIn: BigInt(amountIn), //was amountIn.toString()
                                    amountOut: BigInt(amountOut) //was amountOut.toString()

                                };
                            });

                            console.log(`tradeInstructions`)
                            console.log(tradeInstructions)

                            executeTrades(tradeInstructions, arbitrage, account); 

                        }

                        // isExecuting = false

                } catch (error) {

                    console.error('Error during arbitrage execution:', error);

                } finally {

                    isExecuting = false;  // Ensure the flag is reset regardless of success or failure

                }

            }

        })
})   

}

//Other code here

//This is where I execute the trade

const executeTrades = async (tradeInstructions, arbitrage, account) => {
    
    console.log(`Attempting Arbitrage...\n`)

    const wethContract = new ethers.Contract(wethAddr, WETH_ABI, provider);

    const balanceStart = await wethContract.balanceOf(account)

    console.log(`Balance Start: ${balanceStart}\n`)

    try {

        let totalEstimatedGas = 0

        for (let i = 0; i < tradeInstructions.length; i++) {

            const { arbPair, router, routerTarget, inputToken, outputToken, amountIn, amountOut } = tradeInstructions[i];

            const allowance = await checkAllowance(inputToken, router, amountIn);

            if (!allowance) {

                console.log(`Insufficient allowance for ${inputToken}. Approving...\n`);
                await approveToken(inputToken, router, amountIn);
                console.log(`Final allowance check for ${inputToken}...\n`);
                await checkAllowance(inputToken, router, amountIn);

            }

            // Add trade instruction to the smart contract
            const tx = await arbitrage.addTradeInstruction(
                arbPair,
                router,
                routerTarget,
                inputToken,
                outputToken,
                amountIn,
                amountOut
            );

            await tx.wait();
            
            const estimatedGas = await provider.estimateGas(tx)

            totalEstimatedGas = Number(totalEstimatedGas) + Number(estimatedGas)

            console.log(`tradeInstruction ${i} added. Current total gas: ${totalEstimatedGas}\n`)

        }  

        const tokenAddress = tradeInstructions[0].inputToken; 

        const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, IERC20.abi, signer);

        const doubleAmountIn = Number(tradeInstructions[0].amountIn) *2

        const approvedTxn = await tokenContract.approve(tradeInstructions[0].router.target, doubleAmountIn.toString());

        await approvedTxn.wait();

        const expandedGas = totalEstimatedGas * 2

        console.log("Executing Transaction\n")

        const execTx = await arbitrage.executeSwaps({

            // amount: tradeInstructions[0].amountIn,
            gasLimit: BigInt(expandedGas),

        });

        await execTx.wait();

    } catch (error) {

        console.error("Swap Failed:", error);

    }

    const balanceFinal = await wethContract.balanceOf(account)

    console.log(`Balance Final: ${balanceFinal}\n`)

    const diff = Number(balanceFinal) - Number(balanceStart)

    console.log(`Difference V40: ${diff}\n`)
}


To be honest if it reverts with transferFrom failed, then you either don't have the allowance, or don't have the tokens. Log and step through addresses, balances and allowances at the time of execution. Most likely something is off. A lot of times with these, people forget their contract needs allowance as well as any contract it interacts with that moves tokens from it (like the router which I see you approved). Can avoid that by transferring to pools directly needing only the allowance of arb contract to move from src.

Thanks so much and I'm sorry for the delay!  You and Solidity X below had the same idea, but the error is the same for me.  Feel free to check what s/he said below and I'd love any other ideas you might have!

Apparently the problem was how I called my local node.  I was calling npx hardhat node when I should have called npx hardhat node --fork [MY_API_ENDPOINT]
The reason this is important is that if you don't fork mainnet, you have to essentially create every token you want to experiment with.  Forking mainnet takes that data and works with it instead.

You either do not have enough allowance, however it seems that you give allowance to the router, check if the number is actually in the right format (wei). Check is the owner of the allowance is the caller of the function and not some other account. Check that you have enough tokens and that the amount of tokens are in the right format (wei). Simple multiplication errors could cause that the input it bigger than it should be. Maybe you also just don't have enough input tokens to execute the trade.

Ok, sorry for the delay haha.  I've checked every step of this, and still have the same error.  This is on a local node, so I can see the amount in the account is 10000 WETH being passed in wei, and the allowances are all there.
I thought it might be possible that the loop might be causing the contract to try and execute multiple transactions at the same time rather than sequentially, but I get the same error even if I change the contract to ONLY make the first tx (which is always WETH -> [something]).  Still totally lost on this one.  Other ideas?

Update!  So I realized there was something I hadn't checked - the amount the contract held.  That fixed the TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED error, but I still get an unhelpful "could not coalesce error".  Any ideas how this could be fixed?
